# htaccess deny to URL

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

Is it possible to deny an IP from visiting a specific post on my wordpress blog, maybe by specifying the URL of the post?

Answer (score 0):

```
<Files abc.html>
    order allow,deny
    deny from 123.45.6.7
    deny from 012.34.5.
    deny from netzero.net
    deny from spaceproxy.com 
    allow from all
</Files>
```

You can deny access based upon IP address or an IP block. The above blocks access to the page abc.html from `123.45.6.7`, and from any sub domain under the IP block `012.34.5. (012.34.5.1, 012.34.5.2, 012.34.5.3, etc.)`

.htaccess files are

a) **recursive on subdirectories** and

b) **cumulative in reverse.**

This can be difficult to understand.

-The .htaccess in the root directory applies to everything on the site, because it applies to the subdirectories.

-**An .htaccess in a subdirectory can override stuff that the parent .htaccess has set.**

-**RewriteRules apply in reverse order. That is, the current directory rewrites apply first, then the parents rewrites, and so on.**

**so why dont you just put these new rules mentioned above in a seperate .htaccess file in the directory which contains the post you want to be protected** from a url or an IP.

Comment: Is what Virendar is after is to block just one blog post, not the whole site?

Comment: Yes I just want to block 1 blog post. And Ayush, I use wordpress, so url of the pages are rewritten with mod_rewrite and are not actual html files. example, what if i wanted to block an IP from accessing this specific page: http://bignanime.wordpress.com/2011/01/31/aria-gn-6/

Comment: no I don't think so. there is no "directory." I can change the URLs to anything that i want, the url structure is driven by php. I need htaccess to effect directly to the url. In the above link I posted, where would I put the htaccess file? In 2011 folder? there is no such thing.